# Creating a cascading input control with a multi-select input control

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have to build some cascading multi select input controls in JasperServer Report, but I'm having the same problem as this guy here:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/844760/creating-cascading-input-control-multi-select-input-control

The thread is very old, and people replied him to search for a "Cascading_multi_select_report" sample. I've searched for it, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I'm struggling to make this type of cascading input control... Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check your parameter id name ? Which version of jasper server you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for this, but I may have an answer to help you debug.  
Whenever you are trying to run your report on the jasper server and are just getting a blank page (no input controls), you can use Chrome developer tools or Firebug or whatever browser web developer tool you use (usually Ctrl + Shift + Q will pull it up) and in the Network pane, you can see the requests.  Find the last GET request, and look at the response for it and you can see the error.